# Localhost page is not loading entirely

Tags: localhost, wamp

When I start localhost (wamp server) it only shows me the list of projects and nothing else. Why isn't the page loading completely?

Its not a fresh install and the wampmanager icon is green in color.

I am using OS-Windows 7 64bit, WAMPServer 2.4 64bit, Apache - 2.4.4, MySQL - 5.6.12 and PHP - 5.4.12.

Comment: Come on a little more information required if you actually want an answer!!. What version of OS? What version of Apache, MySQL, PHP? What version of WAMPServer? Is this a fresh install or have you played with it. Has it been working and now stopped? What color is your `wampmanager` icon? Please edit your question with more details!!

Comment: Ya, I do wanted an answer and that's why I've posted a question here! Its not a fresh install and is green in color. OS-Windows 7, Apache - 2.4.4, MySQL - 5.6.12 and PHP - 5.4.12.

Answer (score 0):

This is what the WAMPServer home page should look like what is missing on what you are seeing?

[image]

Comment: Only projects are being seen. Like joomla25 and other too in your case.

Comment: You have probably corrupted the `\wamp\www\index.php` file.

Comment: You could try downloading it from this link http://derp.co.uk/bdd9e I hope this does not add any other corruptions so backup yours just in case I am wrong.